# Can't update: low space in /boot (LVM) - I already cleaned my Lubuntu with Ubuntu Tweak

Tags: boot, lubuntu, gparted, disk-usage, lvm

I have low space on `/boot` partition and I can't update my Lubuntu. I have LVM. I deleted old kernels and used Ubuntu Tweak.

I tried to loaded from LiveCD and with `gparted` grow up my `/boot`-size, but `gparted` not giving me ability to make more space for `/boot` - only to shrink.

[image]

I see hidden folder `.Trash-0` in my `/boot` with old kernels. I can't delete any file in this folder - they are recreating with new number in name. I have empty trash can. How I can delete this files?

Comment: upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: your problem is a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/234514/unable-to-resize-lvm-partition-just-after-ubuntu-install-with-use-lvm-option

Comment: I see hidden folder `.Trash-0` in my `/boot` with old kernels. I can't delete any file in this folder - they are recreating with new number in name. I have empty trash can. How I can delete this files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted kernels in hidden folder `/boot/.Trash-0`. I fix my problem by deleting files in this folder by pressing `SHIFT + DEL`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have lots of old kernels installed. Run this command: `dpkg -l 'linux-image-3*'` and remove all the kernel packages that don't match the running kernel (check with `uname -r`).

Comment: Quote from my question: `I deleted old kernels and used Ubuntu Tweak.`

Comment: THen show us what's in /boot :)

Answer (score 0):

After you delete unneeded files, a simple way to empty /boot/.Trash-0 is:

1) open a terminal

2) use `sudo xterm` (or whatever terminal you like) to open a second terminal session

3) in the second terminal, go to the trash folder with `cd /boot/.Trash-0`

4) check to make sure you're in /boot/.Trash-0 with `pwd`

5) remove everything in .Trash-0 with `rm  -r`  (*be careful, that will remove everything in and below the current directory*)

6) check to confirm everything has been removed with `ls -l`

This works in 14.04 LTS, and probably other versions, but... YMMV.